# Why does strlen give segfault in assembly?

Tags: macos, assembly, apple-m1, arm64

I'm trying to make a request to localhost. I want to know length of my message, but can't figure out what am I doing wrong.
Output is like:

```
    helloS  helloS  helloS  helloS  helloS  helloS  helloS  helloS  helloS  helloS  helloS  helloS  helloS  helloS  helloS  helloS./run.sh: line 1: 10066 Segmentation fault: 11
```

This is what lldb gives:
[image: This is what lldb gives]

Code is [here](https://pastebin.com/e72GNG5w).
But when replace

```
adr x0, _msg
bl _strlen
```

to

```
mov x0, #5
```

everything works fine.

Comment: `add x1, sp, #4` misaligns the stack; IIRC, AArch64 enforces 16-byte stack alignment on at least some instructions, like `stp` which library functions might use. Maybe on the `stur` that faulted.

Comment: It could be misaligned access, yes, but not because of that `add` since that only writes `x1` and is after the fault anyway. Since `sp` is known to be 16 byte aligned, the `[sp, #0x4]` will be misaligned. However that should still crash even with the `mov x0, #5` instead of the `bl _strlen`. Should be easy to change to offset 8 (everywhere) to see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Jester If I change for example ```str x0, [sp, #4]``` to ```str w0, [sp, #4]``` it won't break align rules, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your `_send` implementation doesn't preserve `x30`.

When you hardcode `mov x0, #5`, then there is nothing in that function that corrupts `x30`. But when you call `_strlen`, then that sets `x30` to the address of `str x0, [sp, #4]`, which means that the part of `_send` after the call to `_strlen` will run over and over again, each time increasing `sp` by 16 bytes until you reach the top of the stack and hit unmapped memory.

The fix is to spill `x30` to the stack before the call to `_strlen`, and to reload it from there afterwards.

Comment: I just came accros your ```arm64 assembly crash course``` on github, read about ```x30``` return address and now everything works fine. Impressive guide, thanks!